# Решение задачи с помощью Z-функции

Tags: c++, строки

есть у меня тривиальная реализация Z-функции

```
std::vector<int> z_function (std::string s) {
int n = (int) s.length();
std::vector<int> out (n);
for (int i=1; i<n; ++i)
    while (i + out[i] < n && s[out[i]] == s[i+out[i]])
        ++out[i];
return out;
```

}

Как с помощью этой функции можно решить эту задачу?

> Будем говорить, что символьная строка имеет период k, если она может быть образована путем объединения одной или нескольких одинаковых строк длиной k. Например, строка "abcabcabcabc" имеет период 3, так как она может быть образована путём объединения 4-х строк "abc". Она также имеет период 6 (объединение двух строк "abcabc") и 12 (сама строка "abcabcabcabc").Напишите программу определяющую наименьший период заданной строки.

Вот что у меня получилось но почему-то тесты не проходит

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<int> z_function (std::string s) {
int n = (int) s.length();
std::vector<int> out (n);
for (int i=1; i<n; ++i)
    while (i + out[i] < n && s[out[i]] == s[i+out[i]])
        ++out[i];
return out;
}

int main(){
    int N,counter = 0;
    std::cin >> N;
    std::cin.ignore(1, ' ');
    const int n = 81;
    char *str = new char[n];
    do{
        std::cin.getline(str,n);
        std::vector<int> check = z_function(str);
        int n = check.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if(check[i] == n - i && n % i == 0){
                std::cout << i << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        counter++;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    while(counter < N);
    delete[] str;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Результат работы функции - целочисленный массив, в котором `z[i]` — это длина наибольшего общего префикса строки `s` и её `i`-го суффикса.

Нужно пройти по `z[i]`, проверяя вот что:

Если `z[i]==n-i` и `n%i==0`, то `i` является длиной периода (наименьшее такое `i` - длина наименьшего периода)

Comment: Да,но почему-то не для всех случаев работает

Comment: Есть примеры строк, на которых не работает?

Comment: Например когда вводишь строку "b" ответ должен быть 1

Comment: Но я не говорю что алгоритм неправильный,возможно я неправильно реализовал,посмотрите пожалуйста в вопросе

Comment: Выглядит правильно. Для строки длиной 1 трудно говорить о периоде , нужно просто возвращать 1

Comment: Еще как пример строка "abcdefg" должна возвращать период 7, но код не выводит ничего

Comment: Период есть, если существует некоторое количество повторов. Если вам по какой-то причине нужно непериодическую строку так помечать  -просто выводите длину строки, если в результатах z-функции ничего не нашлось

Comment: Как раз так и сделал,большое спасибо :)